# Documents inside a folder not showing when a filter is applied in query string?

Tags: document-library, filter, query-string

I create a webpart to show the Document List on a certain page, and then I applied a filter on a column content to show only certain documents. But in that way the folder structure is lost and all documents are shown flat.

I want to search recursive inside a document using a query string.

```
https://example.com/folder1/Document%20Library.aspx?RootFolder=/folder2/&FilterName=DocIcon&FilterMultiValue=xls;
```

Now here I want to search recursively inside folder 2

folder 2 contains inner folders and files, here I want to fetch all files.